# Failed gem install: gem require ruby-2.6.1 but the currently ruby-2.6.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-2.6

> Show messages errors:

```
Required ruby-2.6.1 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install "ruby-2.6.1"'
```

> ruby -v

```
ruby 2.6.1p33 (2019-01-30 revision 66950) [x64-mingw32]
```

> rails -v

```
Rails 5.2.2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I doubt that RVM may not be updated to support this version of Ruby. As I know the following version is supported, you can version by following command and response should match.

```
rvm --version
1.29.7
```

If you have updated version then I will do the following to check if RVM has also the same version of ruby installed.

I will check the content of my project root folder's following file

```
cat .ruby-version
```

If it has mention same, as rvm is also complaining that I will run the following command on rvm to check if this ruby is really installed in RVM

```
rvm list
```

It will show a list of rubies installed and it should include 2.6.1 in the end. If you can't see this list then you probably need to install using the following command

```
rvm install "ruby-2.6.1"
```

If it is showing than can you try the following command and see what result comes

```
rvm use 2.6.1
```

If all good, then try the following command to see which ruby is being used

```
which ruby
```

response must include `.rvm/rubies/` mean you are using .rvm ruby otherwise, you may using the system built in ruby.
Just wrote may help you to diagnos issue.

Comment: You have to install ruby try `rvm install "ruby-2.6.1"`

Comment: **rvm --version**
`rvm 1.29.7-next (master) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]`
**cat .ruby-version**
`ruby-2.6.1`
**rvm list**
`# No rvm rubies installed yet. Try 'rvm help install'.`

Comment: **rvm install "ruby-2.6.1"**
`Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: mingw/unknown/x86_64/ruby-2.6.1.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more informatio
Checking requirements for mingw.
Requirements support for mingw is not implemented yet,
report a bug here => https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues
Requirements installation failed with status: 1` **and It's show warning**

Comment: **Warning**
`Warning, new version of rvm available '1.29.7', you are using older version '1.29.7-next'.
You can disable this warning with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=0 >> ~/.rvmrc
You can enable  auto-update  with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc`

Comment: which OS you are using? please do `echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc` and try again to install `rvm install "ruby-2.6.1"`

Comment: I used windows 10, I'm trying to install again like you tell, but It's show the same errors. hmmm

Comment: Well honestly I don't use windows from 6 years, so my suggestion why do you need 2.6.1? it is very latest and will take time, you can use 2.5.1 you have to go in your project folder and change `.ruby-version` and change Gemfile where ruby version is mentioned. I leave you here as I don't use windows.

Comment: Excuse me brother! I had downgrade ruby version to 2.2.6 but It's still alert me `Required ruby-2.2.6 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install "ruby-2.2.6"'
`

Comment: try to run command `rvm install "ruby-2.2.6"` and if still have problem seems you have the problem with RVM installation, so following [https://rvm.io/rubies/removing]

Comment: Thank you very much brother, I had fixed it.

Comment: if my answer helps you then accept the answer by click tick mark, if there was another problem, please share so people can know issue and it helps others. Thank you.

Comment: That problems I'm not sure, but when I change path in my computer. It's don't have problem when I run it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv)? If so, I'd recommend running `rvm implode` as described [here](https://installvirtual.com/how-to-uninstall-rvm-implode-rvm-on-mac/).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using **rbenv**

see if you have it available in your list :

```
rbenv install --list | grep 2.6.1
```

if not, fetch it

```
cd ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build && git pull && cd -
```

now if you try again

```
rbenv install -l | grep 2.6.1
```

so just run the installation command:

```
rbenv install 2.6.1
```

> ```
> Downloading ruby-2.6.1.tar.bz2...  08:36:17
> -> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.6/ruby-2.6.1.tar.bz2
> Installing ruby-2.6.1...
> Installed ruby-2.6.1 to ~/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1
> ```

now you can use it for global or local projects. if local :

```
rbenv local 2.6.1
```